# Get closest timespan to TimeOfDay from collection

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to get a timespan from a collection of timespan which is the closest to the current timeofday.

Atm i have the following code:

```
var closestTime= timespanCollection.OrderBy(t => Math.Abs((t - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).Ticks)).First();
```

the problem is that when the time is for example 11:02 and there is a time of 11:00, it will give this as the closest but i only want times that are in the future.

What would be a fast way of doing this, i was guesing with like a foreach loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input data ?

Comment: `timespanCollection.Where(t => t > DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).OrderBy(...)`?

Comment: Don't user Math.Abs as it converts the negative to positive.  `var closestTime= timespanCollection.OrderBy(t => (t - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).Ticks).First();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Where` to get only future timespans. You can also use `TimeSpan.Duration` instead of `Math.Abs`:

```
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan closestTime = timespanCollection
    .Where(ts => ts > now)
    .OrderBy(ts => (ts - now).Duration())
    .First();
```